# How do I get a vector of u8 RGB values when using the image crate?

Tags: rust

I need to take an image and get a list of RGB byte values. I am using [the image crate](https://crates.io/crates/image). This is what I have:

```
extern crate image;

fn main() {
    let im = image::open("wall.jpg").unwrap().to_rgb();
    let data: Vec<[u8; 3]> = im.pixels().flat_map(|p| vec![p.data]).collect();
    let rgb: Vec<&u8> = data.iter().flat_map(|p| p.iter()).collect();
    println!("First Pixel: {} {} {}", rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
}
```

This seems pretty ugly. I have to introduce an intermediate variable and I get a vector of pointers to the values I really need, so before I can do something else, I would have to map over it again to get the actual values.

All I want is a vector of `u8`. How do I get that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of 0.23.12, [`to_rgb`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.to_rgb) has been deprecated use [`DynamicImage::to_rgb8`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.to_rgb8) or [`DynamicImage::to_bytes`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.to_bytes) instead:

```
let im = image::open("wall.jpg").unwrap().to_rgb8();
let rgb: Vec<u8> = im.into_raw();

// Alternatively
let bytes = image::open("wall.jpg").unwrap().to_bytes();
```

Prior to 0.23.12, if you just want the raw data itself, you can just call [`DynamicImage::raw_pixels`](https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.raw_pixels):

```
let im = image::open("wall.jpg").unwrap().to_rgb();
let rgb: Vec<u8> = im.raw_pixels();
```

If all you're actually interested in is the first pixel though, I'd recommend calling [`GenericImage::get_pixel`](https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/trait.GenericImage.html#tymethod.get_pixel):

```
let im = image::open("wall.jpg").unwrap();
let first_pixel = im.get_pixel(0, 0);
```

Which you can then turn into a `[u8; 3]` array of RGB data:

```
let rgb = first_pixel.to_rbg();
println!("First Pixel: {} {} {}", rgb.data[0], rgb.data[1], rgb.data[2]);
```

Comment: I will try your first suggestion, thanks. I am trying to do OpenGL in Rust and working on loading a texture into a buffer. As far as I can tell I need to point the GL API call to a buffer with RGB bytes.